# Java bean mapper expected capture but is provided object

Tags: java, generics, java-11, dozer, erasure

**Please note:** even though I mention [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) in this question, I do believe its really just a pure Java generics question at heart. There *may* be a Dozer-specific solution out there, but I think anyone with strong working knowledge of Java (11) generics/captures/erasures should be able to help me out!

---

Java 11 and Dozer here. Dozer is great for applying default bean mapping rules to field names, but anytime you have specialized, custom mapping logic you need to implement a Dozer `CustomConverter` and register it. That would be great, except the Dozer API for `CustomConverter` isn't genericized, is monolithic and leads to nasty code like this:

```
public class MyMonolithicConverter implements CustomConverter {

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {

        if (sourceClass.isAssignableFrom(Widget.class)) {
          Widget widget = (Widget)source;
          if (destinationClass.isAssignableFrom(Fizz.class)) {
            Fizz fizz = (Fizz)destination;
            // write code for mapping widget -> fizz here
          } else if (destinationClass.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class)) {
            // write code for mapping widget -> foo here
          }
          ... etc.
        } else if (sourceClass.isAssignableFrom(Baz.class)) {
          // write all the if-else-ifs and mappings for baz -> ??? here
        }

    }
}
```

So again: monolithic, not genericized and leads to large, complex nested if-else-if blocks. Eek.

I'm trying to make this a wee bit more palatable:

```
public abstract class BeanMapper<SOURCE,TARGET> {

    private Class<SOURCE> sourceClass;
    private Class<TARGET> targetClass;

    public abstract TARGET map(SOURCE source);

    public boolean matches(Class<?> otherSourceClass, Class<?> otherTargetClass) {
        return sourceClass.equals(otherSourceClass) && targetClass.equals(otherTargetClass);
    }

}
```

Then, an example of it in action:

```
public class SignUpRequestToAccountMapper extends BeanMapper<SignUpRequest, Account> {

    private PlaintextEncrypter encrypter;

    public SignUpRequestToAccountMapper(PlaintextEncrypter encrypter) {
        this.encrypter = encrypter;
    }

    @Override
    public Account map(SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {

        return Account.builder()
            .username(signUpRequest.getRequestedName())
            .email(signUpRequest.getEmailAddr())
            .givenName(signUpRequest.getFirstName())
            .surname(signUpRequest.getLastName()())
            .dob(DateUtils.toDate(signUpRequest.getBirthDate()))
            .passwordEnc(encrypter.saltPepperAndEncrypt(signUpRequest.getPasswordPlaintext()))
            .build();

    }
}
```

And now a way to invoke the correct source -> target mapper from inside my Dozer converter:

```
public class DozerConverter implements CustomConverter {

    private Set<BeanMapper> beanMappers;

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {

        BeanMapper<?,?> mapper = beanMappers.stream()
            .filter(beanMapper -> beanMapper.matches(sourceClass, destinationClass))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();

        // compiler error here:
        return mapper.map(source);

    }
}
```

I **really like** this design/API approach, however I get a compiler error on that `mapper.map(source)` line at the very end:

> "*Required type: capture of ?; Provided: Object*"

**What can I do to fix this compiler error?** I'm not married to this API/approach, but I do like the simplicity it adds over the `MyMonolithicConverter` example above, which is the approach Dozer sort of forces on you. It is important to note that I am using Dozer elsewhere for simple bean mappings so I would prefer to use a `CustomConverter` impl and leverage Dozer for this instead of bringing in a whole other dependency/library for these custom/complex mappings. If Dozer offers a different solution I might be happy with that as well. Otherwise I just need to fix this *capture issue*. Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to come from the `beanMappers`. You have a set of mappers of various types. The compiler cannot infer what types the found `mapper` will have.

You can make the compiler believe you by casting the result and suppress the warning it gives you.

Casting to a `<?,?>` isn't going to happen, so I've added symbols for the convert method. At least it can then be assumed that when you get a `BeanMapper<S,T>`, `map` will indeed return a `T` upon an `S` source.

```java
class DozerConverter {

  private Set<BeanMapper<Object,Object>> beanMappers;

  public <S,T> T convert(S source,
                         Class<?> destinationClass, 
                         Class<?> sourceClass) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    BeanMapper<S,T> mapper = (BeanMapper<S,T>) beanMappers.stream()
        .filter(beanMapper -> beanMapper.matches(sourceClass, destinationClass))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();

    return mapper.map(source);
  }

}
```

I'm afraid you're going to have to call it like so:

```java
TARGET-TYPE target = dozerConverter.<SOURCE-TYPE,TARGET-TYPE>convert(...);
```